# How include and read HTML for a XML?

Tags: php, html, xml, simplexml, cdata

```
<myxml>
  <bla>
    I want <strong>HTML here</strong>
  </bla>
</myxml>
```

How can I read the HTML from the XML document?

```
$data = file_get_contents('myxml.xml');
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($data);
print_r($xml); // fail...
```

ps: without escaping, because it's annoying to escape the text each time I add something..

---

edit:

```
<myxml>
  <bla><![CDATA[I want <strong>HTML here</strong>]]></bla>
</myxml>
```

the PHP:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file('myxml.xml');
print_r($xml);
```

and the output is:

```
SimpleXMLElement Object
(
    [bla] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
        )

)
```

no cdata there..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Surround your `I want <strong>HTML here</strong>` with [`CDATA`](http://www.lshift.net/blog/2007/10/25/xml-cdata-and-escaping) tags, as such:

```
<![CDATA[
    I want <strong>HTML here</strong>
]]>
```

This will tell parsers to ignore what's inside the CDATA block and just parse it as plaintext.

Comment: @Natasha: You are using `SimpleXMLElement` wrong. Use [`simplexml_load_file()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.simplexml-load-file.php) to load the `'myxml.xml'` file.

Comment: @Natasha: Without seeing your code nobody can help you. It's best when you replace the code in your question with your _current_ code sample.

Comment: As for seeing CDATA, `print_r()` treats node as an object and therefore does not print CDATA. You must explicitly cast it to string, when printing, i.e., `echo (string)$xml->bla;`. Edit: when using `echo`, it also works without casting ;)

Comment: @Natasha: `SimpleXMLElement` needs explicit typecasting if you want to print its value. See [this codepad sample](http://codepad.org/0l8bShfO).

Comment: @Tomalak Please read my comment below. Explicit typecasting is **not** required.

Answer (score 0):

Explicit typecast is **not** required for text nodes, and it works only there; `print_r()` is the wrong function/language feature to use here (use `echo` instead).

For printing the content of any SimpleXML element as XML (one that may also contain other elements), use its [asXML()](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.asxml.php) method.